# Input with scanf() on two lines

Tags: c, numbers, scanf, lines

So, in the terminal, my whole program output in C is supposed to look like this (text between ** is user input)

```
**Ax Ay alpha**

**Bx By beta**

d Cx Cy
```

My current code accepts only the first line, the second line is somehow not scanned and it instead tries to give me output already. Here's the input line of code, I think the problem is just in that part.

```
scanf("%2f %2f %2f", &Ax, &Ay, &alpha );
scanf("%2f %2f %2f", &Bx, &By, &beta );
```

Whole code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define PI 3.14159265

int main(){
    float alpha, beta, Ax, Ay, Bx, By;
    float d, Cx, Cy;

    scanf("%2f %2f %2f", &Ax, &Ay, &alpha );
    scanf("%2f %2f %2f", &Bx, &By, &beta );

    /* calculaions are here, whole lot of mess */

    printf("%.2f %.2f %.2f \n", d, Cx, Cy );
}
```

The problem is following: I input the first three variables - the Ax, Ay and alpha. Then, when I press enter, what I want it to do is to let me input the Bx, By and beta too. Instead, it already shows me the results and ends the program.

Comment: pease explain this **and it instead tries to give me output already** and post the resto of the code.

Comment: You need to consume the newline after the first `scanf`, change to `scanf(" %2f %2f %2f", &Bx, &By, &beta );` Notice the space before the first `%2f`

Comment: @AlterMann that's only for `"'%c"` amd `"%[]"` specifiers.

Comment: No, it's not. @AlterMann you were a few seconds quicker than I, saying the same thing. If you want to make that an answer, I'll take mine down.

Comment: @Wintermute it doesn't work, did you test it...

Comment: Yes, I did. Glibc on Linux behaves this way.

Comment: @iharob Added the rest of the code excluding calculations, those were a whole lot of mess and just assigning values to the variables, so I don't think it's a problem.I tried putting the space in front of first %2f, it's not the solution.

Comment: @OP , do you type values or just those characters?

Comment: @Wintermute, no problem ;) iharob makes me doubt, I think he's right

Comment: There is a clause in the standard saying that (overlooked it before; 7.9.16.2 (8)), so glibc's behavior might be buggy. (Using 2.19)

Comment: @CoolGuy I type the values of Ax, Ay, alpha, then press enter and type values of Bx, By and beta, so yes

Comment: Why the 2 in `%2f`? That limits the scanning to 2 digits. If the input value is 408 only 40 gets read. I'd use `if (scanf("%f%f%f", &Ax, &Ay, &alpha) != 3) /* error */;`

Comment: @AlterMann tried adding the space, it's not working...

Comment: @pmg it's a limit I've got to work... I suppose I could have the input be of unlimited lenght, then round it, but I don't know yet if it will be accepted

Just read your edit, that sounds like a better idea

Comment: @Alter Mann `"%f"` even without a leading space, first consumes leading white-space before attempting to scan a `float`.  Adding a `" "` before `"%f"` does **not** additionally help consume spaces or new-lines.  "Input white-space characters (as specified by the `isspace` function) are skipped, unless the specification includes a `[`, `c`, or `n` specifier." C11dr §7.21.6.2 8.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect it's a locale issue, try checking `scanf()` return value to see if the input matched the format string

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float Ax, Ay, Bx, By, alpha, beta;

    if (scanf("%f%f%f", &Ax, &Ay, &alpha) != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (scanf("%f%f%f", &Bx, &By, &beta) != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

that is a clear of example of the kind of problems that appear when you misuse a function, `scanf()` has a return value for a reason.

Test the code with integer numbers and if it works, switch the decimal separator from `'.'` to `','` or viceversa.

Also, it could be that you are limiting the input to 2 characters, which is a problem for almost any floating point number, since `1.2` has 3 characters, remove that.

Comment: Why did you include `limits.h`?

Answer (score 0):

What did you want to achieve with `%2f`? That will limit scanning to 2 digits. I think you just want to print two decimal places after zero:

replace `"%2f"` with `"%0.2f"`, In other words do this:

```
float a, b, c, d, e, f;
scanf("%f %f %f", &a, &b, &c);
scanf("%f %f %f", &d, &e, &f);
printf("%0.2f %0.2f %0.2f\n", a+b, d+e, f+c);
```

and your program will work correctly. The `%2f` is causing the behavior you described.

Comment: Whenever user input may be a problem, which is 99% of the time, robust code checks the return value of `scanf()`.  Otherwise this is a fine answer.